# odin twrp install hangs galaxy s7 edge G935

Tags: samsung, twrp, odin, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I have a new Verizon S7 Edge.  I want to flash twrp using odin.

I am using

- Windows 10
- Odin 3.10.1
- twrp-3.0.0-1-hero2lte.tar.md5

My phone settings are:

- USB debugging on
- OEM Unlock on
- Android 6.0.1
- Build number APB1
- Phone model SM-G935V

When I run odin it hangs when flashing the image.  Here is the output:

```
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> twrp-3.0.0-1-hero2lte.tar.md5 is valid.
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<ID:0/003> Added!!
<ID:0/003> Odin v.3 engine (ID:3)..
<ID:0/003> File analysis..
<ID:0/003> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/003> Initialzation..
<ID:0/003> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/003> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/003> SingleDownload.
<ID:0/003> recovery.img
<ID:0/003> NAND Write Start!!
```

After waiting for a few minutes I unplug the phone and odin dutifully complete with these three lines:

```
<ID:0/003> Complete(Write) operation failed.
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
<ID:0/003> Removed!!
```

As far as I can tell, all of the other threads about this type of problem are not specific to my model phone.

In the past, I have used odin to flash twrp onto various phones including a Samsung Note 4 with no problems.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you try the latest version of Odin (3.10.7) from [here](http://www.droidviews.com/download-odin-tool-for-samsung-galaxy-devices-all-versions/)?  It seems to be the suggested version for Marshmallow.  Make sure you are using the "AP/PDA" tab for your recovery tar file.  Also, I don't see a 3.0.0-1 version of TWRP on their [official site](https://dl.twrp.me/hero2lte/).

Answer (score 1):

It's because your s7 edge from Verizon has locked bootloader and you cannot flash a customer recovery via Odin due to twrp not being an official samsung signed tar or md5 file and your phone rejects it.. also because your not rooted either and may never be unfortunately..  I'm in the same boat and recommend disabling verizon ota updates with package disabler pro apk to stay on the build apb1 to heighten your chances of possibly getting rooted because security patches are added to every update..

Comment: I second that.. I ditched Verizon for this very reason.